# Hibernate writes in the wrong database connected by WildFly datasource

Tags: database, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I'm using Red Hat CodereadyStudio to write a Java EE application, I use Postgres as the database server and I have three databases in it: EsercitazioneNegozio, andreascopp and postgres as you can see in the pgAdmin screenshot here:

[image: pgAdmin databases list]

I have set the `persistence.xml` file using Forge on CodereadyStudio and this is the connection tab where you can see the JNDI on JBoss used as datasource

[image: persistence.xml connection section]

and this is the JBoss resume of the datasource

[image: JBoss datasource resume]

Now the problem is that every time I create a table it is written in `andreascopp` even if I the datasource has the `EsercitazioneNegozio`'s URL.
How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning your project if you are using eclipse.

Go to Menu option –> Select Project –> click Clean… Clicking Clean options in Eclipse IDE provides 2 options, which allows to select desired projects to be cleaned.

Comment: It did not work, I actually have already tried to set it all up from the beginning, including uninstalling and reinstalling Postgres